# How to pick image from Photos Library in iPad using iOS6?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I have tried to implement the code for picking image from photos library in iPad using iOS6 but it is not working. The code i tried is shown below.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePickerController.delegate=self;

    UIPopoverController *popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];

    popover.delegate=self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {

        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(400, 400, 0, 0) inView:self.view
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Can any one please tell me the solution for this issue.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`?

Comment: Ya, i have tried. I can say the problem is with the orientation. but i don't know how to solve it.